# How to embed a link to corresponding (page) always open in my browser Safari?

Tags: safari, links

I have a MacOS on a MacAir laptop and a Safari browser. I have a link to certain page which contains a single image and a title (not many words). I want to somehow embed the link in such a way that this page (image/title or title only) opens spontaneously in a small fraction of my window in same way as certain advertisements always open (of pages one frequently visits and their relative content) each time the browser is opened?
The idea is that who opens the browser, earlier or later, will take notice of this "advertisement" and click on the page/see the content.
I am only interested to make this on my own computer and temporarily (and after some time I'll need to "uninstall" this link or "add"). 
Please, advise me if it is doable and how exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this site is the best place for your question as it's basically a web design/HTML question. However one simple way to achieve this would be to create an image as your _advertisement_ and then just use HTML to load it and link to the other page.

Comment: I agree, it's a web design/HTML question. This is usually done with Javascript, PHP, VBScript, etc.

Comment: Dear Monomeeth, I still have not solved the problem. I perfectly see that this task is not exactly matching the focus of this site but you were the only one to suggest a solution. Could you help me along the lines of your suggestion? I have a link to the image, it looks like that "https:// etc. etc." How I can use HTML to make it appear in my browser. I do not have obvious access to the web pages content that open in it ... Sorry for the illiteracy but I am not familiar with web design at all. I was thinking to use injection script in Safari Extension Builder, but could not do it. Many thanks.